# jQuery Ajax call seems to be failing but file exist

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code which does an AJAX call to this specific file '/errorData/errorMessage.json' in my server and then never calls the `.done` function.

The file exist and I double checked the URL, I basically typed the URL: `localhost/../errorData/errorMessage.json` and it shows the content of this json file.

I even checked the apache2 log file and the error doesn’t file `file doesnt exist` and I also checked the firefox debugger window it doesn’t say GET failed.

This code worked when I ran it from a different server but since I moved it to a different server, it doesn’t work any more.

```
function getErrorMessage()
{
    $.ajax({
        url: "../errorData/errorMessage.json",
        cache: false
    })
    .done(function( data ) 
    {
        if(isEmpty(data) || isBlank(data)) {    
            $('.panel-danger').hide("fast")
            //audio.stop();
        }
        else {
            $('.panel-body').html(data);
            $('.panel-danger').show("fast")
            //audio.play();
        }   
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(getErrorMessage,2000);
    getErrorMessage();
});
```

Comment: How do you expect to go up a level from http://localhost

Comment: I use htaccess to redirect the page containing this js to a cgi-bin file, so from that location it has to move up one location and as I mentioned, viewing the firefox debug messages, It is successfully fetching the file OK.

Comment: The path is not relative to the JS file. The path is relative to the HTML file.

Comment: Like I said, it has no issue fetching it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify data type as JSON. According to [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/), You can either `use $.getJSON` or

```
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success
});
```

to load JSON.

Hope it helps

Comment: This is a better answer than mine, so I switched my answer to yours.

Comment: The even better alternative is to make sure the JSON is served using mime-type text/json or application/json, then you don't have to specify the type on the client, it's inferred.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `../` in a url. It does not work like you expect. You need to either have the full absolute url or starting at the root begin with a `/` and include the remaining path. For example

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/my/file.json
```

Or starting at the root:

```
/path/to/my/file.json
```

Comment: I tried removing the `../` And still no difference. As I mentioned above, when I check the firefox debug windows it shows that is was able to grab the file OK. Also I have a similar ajax call that uses `../` and that one works.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. When using `$.ajax` it doesn’t work if the file has `.json` extension. It works with `.html` extension though.

Comment: absolutely, but not with `$.ajax` call.